# How to get one line and Three colums in SQL (using the sum of costs for each menssenger)?

Tags: sqlite, pivot, case, aggregate-functions

[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBvLB.png)

The following queries are getting me 3 lines but it's not what I want to get, I want to get 1 line and 3 columns, could you help me, please?

```
Select NoMess,
  case 
    when (NoMess = "1") Then (SELECT SUM (Port) from commande where NoMess = "1") 
    when (NoMess = "2") Then (SELECT SUM (Port) from commande where NoMess = "2") 
    when (NoMess = "3") Then (SELECT SUM (Port) from commande where NoMess = "3") 
  End as Port
From Commande 
Group by NoMess
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN NoMess = '1' THEN Port ELSE 0 END) AS column1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NoMess = '2' THEN Port ELSE 0 END) AS column2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NoMess = '3' THEN Port ELSE 0 END) AS column3
FROM Commande
```